# Redis Template won't serialize key and value

Tags: kotlin, serialization, redis, spring-data-redis

I want to use RedisTemplate on spring boot. This is my configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
class RedisConfig {

    @Value("\${spring.redis.host}")
    lateinit var redisHost: String

    @Value("\${spring.redis.port}")
    lateinit var redisPort: String

    @Bean
    fun redisConnectionFactory(): JedisConnectionFactory? {
        val redisStandaloneConfiguration = RedisStandaloneConfiguration()
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.hostName = redisHost
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.port = redisPort.toInt()
        return JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration)
    }

    @Bean
    fun redisTemplate(): RedisTemplate<Int, String> {
        val redisTemplate = RedisTemplate<Int, String>()
        val stringSerializer: RedisSerializer<String> = StringRedisSerializer()
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory()!!)
        redisTemplate.keySerializer = stringSerializer
        redisTemplate.valueSerializer = stringSerializer
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet()
        return redisTemplate
    }
}
```

In my class i've got something like this:

```
@Service
class UserService {

    @Autowired
    var redisTemplate = RedisTemplate<Int, String>()

    val user = User("1", "Mike", "Tobey", "Male", "MT@gmail.com")
    val user1 = User("1", "Mike", "Tobey", "Male", "MT@gmail.com")


    fun foo(user: User, user1: User) {
        if (user.lastName == user1.lastName && user.firstName == user1.firstName) {
            redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(user.hashCode(), user.id)
        } else if (user.gender == user1.gender && user.firstName == user1.firstName) {
            redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(user1.hashCode(), user1.id)
        }
    }
```

The `User.class` is marked as `@Serializable` and `@RedisHash`. In the `redisTemplate.opsForValue().set()` method, it won't recognize the key and the value at all. This is what the program returns me:
`Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializer.serialize(Object)" because the return value of "org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.valueSerializer()" is null`.

Can anybody help?

I tried to set key and values in value store for redisTemplate but it seems like code won't serialize those values.